# where is my app_data folder on Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, app-data

I am deploying my project to Azure. I'm checking the files that have been deployed and I can't seem to find App_Data folder in there (which contains some important files for my project).

How can I make the 'Publish' process actually adding the App_Data folder to the published package?

Comment: are you deploying to an azure VM for azure WebSites ?

Comment: @BrijRajSingh I am deploying to Azure Websites. Why?